# HTML table with database values

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've created an HTML table with database values

```
<?php
include 'conexao.php';
echo "<div id='table'>
      <table >
          <tr>
              <th class='first'>Selecione</th>
              <th>Mês</th>
              <th>Valor</th>
          </tr>";
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM cpf');
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr>
              <td class='first'><input type='radio' name='selecione'/></td>
              <td>". $row['mes'] ."</td>
              <td>". number_format($row['valor'], 2, ',', '.') ."</td>
          </tr>";
} 
echo "</table></div>";
?>
```

Well, it works great, but when I have many values, I have to scroll down the page. I would like to create "page numbers" for my table when I have more than 10 values for example.

Something like this: http://www.phpgrid.org/demo-center/

Observation: I wouldn't like to get the table done like the table from the link, because I want to apply my styles to table...

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think you need pagination in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those cases like yours, I usually use php pagination. I think if you would like to do so, the following links will help you.

> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm
>   
>   http://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=289

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To do it in the database (SQL-Server syntax):

```
DECLARE @tmpSearch TABLE (  
        RowNumber INT IDENTITY(0,1),
        Name VARCHAR(4000)
)


INSERT @tmpSearch 
EXEC [dbo].[spSearch]
@SearchTerm

SELECT * 
FROM @tmpSearch 
WHERE RowNumber >= (@PageNo-1) * @PageSize 
AND RowNumber < (@PageNo * @PageSize)  
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

`@tmpSearch` needs the same columns as `[dbo].[spSearch]` and the `RowNumber` column